# Crashlytics for ios in Xcode 7.1, throwing multiple errors after adding the framework in xcode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode7, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I am using Xcode 7.1. I did the installation of the Crashlytics for my iOS app. I went to their website, downloaded it and did the steps for the integration of their framework. It suggests me to do the clean build, which I did with no success. I am attaching the snapshot for the same.
[image]
 The Xcode is throwing around 20 errors and I am clueless how to proceed after this.

[image]

Comment: can you use cocoa pod crashlytics ? 
please tell us how do u imprt craslytics in project and code

Comment: did you try my Answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please import
`libc++` (not libstdc++)
`libz`, `SystemConfiguration.framework`, and `Security.framework`

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the link in the fabric that gives a detailed solution to the problem, it is 
[How do I fix linker errors when adding Fabric?](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/617277)